# how to make an undo button for a dynamically made checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I populate the page using javascript/jquery and html, it adds a check box when you hit add, i was just wondering a way to add an undo button to delete the last checkbox made.

heres the js fiddle for what i have

[My code JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kf2mq20e/)

code snippet:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
     txtName.value="";
    });
 });

  function addCheckbox(name) {
    var container = $('#cblist');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length+1;

    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
    $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
    $('<br/>').appendTo(container);
    //dino
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kf2mq20e/1/

HTML

```
<h1 id="tit">New CheckList Template </h1>
<hr><br>

<form action="page being sent to">
Company Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br><br>




<div id="cblist">

</div>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="Add Checkbox" id="btnSave" />
<input type="button" value="Remove Checkbox" id="btnRemove" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save Company Template">
<input TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Restart Template">
</form>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
             txtName.value="";
        });
        $("#btnRemove").click(removeCheckbox);

    });

    function addCheckbox(name) {
       var container = $('#cblist');
       var inputs = container.find('input');
       var id = inputs.length+1;

       $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
       $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
       $('<br/>').appendTo(container);

    }

    function removeCheckbox(){
        var container = $('#cblist');
        container.children('input').last().remove();
        container.children('label').last().remove();
        container.children('br').last().remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a remove button that once clicked queries the checkbox inputs and removes the last, like so

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#cblist input').last().remove();
    $('#cblist label').last().remove();
    $('#cblist br').last().remove();
});
```

Comment: this deletes the checkbox bot not the text that goes along with it

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your newly added elements in a mini container before appending them to the `cblist`, and when removing the last checkbox you remove the container together with the label and the line break element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSave').click(function() {
    addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
    txtName.value = "";
  });
  $('#btnRemove').click(function() {
    $(".New_CB").last().remove();
  });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
  var container = $('#cblist');
  var inputs = container.find('input');
  var id = inputs.length + 1;

  var CBContainer = $("<span class='New_CB'/>");
  $('<input />', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'cb' + id,
    value: name
  }).appendTo(CBContainer);
  $('<label />', {
    'for': 'cb' + id,
    text: name
  }).appendTo(CBContainer);
  $('<br/>').appendTo(CBContainer);
  CBContainer.appendTo(container);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="tit">New CheckList Template </h1>
<hr>
<br>

<form action="page being sent to">
  Company Name:
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="cblist">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" />
  <input type="button" value="Add Checkbox" id="btnSave" />
  <input type="button" value="Remove Checkbox" id="btnRemove" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Company Template">
  <input TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Restart Template">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Find and remove last added checkbox.

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
         txtName.value="";
    });
    $('#removeCheckbox').click(function(){
    var cb=$( "#cblist input" ).last();
    if(cb && cb.length){
       cb.remove();
    }
});
});
function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   checkbox= $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
   $('<br/>').appendTo(container);

}
```

HTML :

```
<h1 id="tit">New CheckList Template </h1>
<hr><br>

<form action="page being sent to">
Company Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br><br>




<div id="cblist">

</div>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="Add Checkbox" id="btnSave" />
<input type="button" value="Remove Checkbox" id="removeCheckbox" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save Company Template">
<input TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Restart Template">
</form>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/kf2mq20e/10/